# SSDs with the Intel RMS25CB080

Tags: raid, ssd

I've bought a new server which only allows disks to be connected to a built-in Intel RMS25CB080 RAID controller card. The server has 8 2.5" slots.

I'm considering using SSDs with this server, however I'm not interested in having the SSDs in a RAID configuration owing to the lack of TRIM support (it's 2015, why isn't TRIM supported in RAID1/5/10 yet?), so the SSDs would have to be in a "passthrough" configuration, however I cannot see anything in the manual about presenting single physical disks as-is to the hardware's operating system.

The documentation of the controller says it does support certain "Non-disk" devices, I found this thread from February 2013 talking about support for Intel 530-series SSDs ( https://communities.intel.com/thread/36368 ) however it doesn't explain what exactly it means to support SSDs. Does this mean the controller **does** send TRIM commands to the SSDs (even in various RAID configurations) or something else?

Answer (score 0):

The traditional method to enable quasi-direct access to the sigle disks in absence of a true passthrough feature is to create multiple single-disk RAID0 arrays (one array for each disk).

Then, you can test trim functionality using an appropriate program as [trimchecker](https://github.com/CyberShadow/trimcheck)